Why does TypeScript not know that Object.entries() of a Partial object could contain undefined values?
const example: Partial<{ a: string }> = { a: undefined };
const value = example.a; // type is string | undefined
const values = Object.values(example); // type is string[] (!?)

In the code block above, value has type string | undefined, but values has type string[]. Why is this? I would expect values to have type Array<string | undefined>.
Playground link with some more details

Related question. Basically, you may want to activate the --exactOptionalPropertyTypes compiler option to differentiate between "inexistent key" and "existing key with an undefined value".

Not quite. You can try toggling this option on and off in the playground. While it does help prevent assigning a: undefined to the example object, it has no effect on the type of values.

With this option, you now have to explicitly type the undefined value possibility (if it's what is wanted), and Object.entries() and Object.values() work just fine in this case. Could you update the playground to show a situation where it doesn't work?

Look at the linked q/a above and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44494. @Blackhole is correct; if you enable --exactOptionalPropertyTypes you'll get the behavior you want, since {x?: 0} and {x?: 0 | undefined} will now be different types, and Object.entries and Object.values will treat them differently. It might not be possible for you to enable that, but that's the basic problem: without that flag enabled, TS really can't properly distinguish between "missing" and "present-but-undefined" and it behaves inconsistently in cases where that difference matters.

@Blackhole Sure, here's an updated playground link.

@jcalz I understand --exactOptionalPropertyTypes, but I still don't love how Object.values() is behaving here.

What behaviour are you expecting? The only possible elements of example are string, so there is no reason for Object.values() to include undefined, the same way you wouldn't expect Object.keys() to include a, b, c… and every possible keys. If you want to include undefined, type it explicitly: Partial<{a: string | undefined}>.

"The only possible elements of example are string" Yes, when --exactOptionalPropertyTypes is enabled. But when it's disabled, that's not true. I would expect the type of values to be string[] with the option enabled, and I would expect it to be Array<string | undefined> with it disabled.

Well, that's not the way it is, because of the ambiguity of undefined without the option, as explained above.

Without --exactOptionalPropertyTypes, it's unambiguous that values should be Array<string | undefined> but I can accept that this is just the way it is.

Ok wait a second. This works: Object.values<string | undefined>(example) .

Anyhow, I think that's enough comments for now. Thanks for the help
